# Javascript: Uncaught Type error Autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm aware that this question has been posted a lot as I have been going through every answer trying to find a solution but it has not worked for my code.

I'm trying to call the autocomplete function using jquery-ui on my search bar, but every time I load the page I get the type error saying autocomplete is not a function.

I've removed every instance of loading the javascript ui and placed it in a seperate file in my javascript folder called "jquery-ui-src.php", which looks like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

which is then called in files that need to use the jquery-ui. The file where the error is being caught I think is in my "header.php" file that acts as a header for the whole site

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("assets/js/jquery-ui-src.php");
 ?> 
<header id="header" class="website-header">

//other code included here

//code for the search bar

<form role="search" action="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>search" method="GET" style="width: 12em; margin: 0.1em 2em;margin-left:7em">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="tags" class="search-field form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

//other code included here




<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#account-dropdown").click(function(){
        $("#account-box").slideToggle(400);
        $(this).css("color", "white");
        return false;
    });                         
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });

});
</script>
</header>
```

Whenever the page loads I get the error saying that autocomplete is not a function and I really can't figure out why it's doing this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT

I've removed the second instance in the header file where the jquery script was called and I'm still getting the error.

Additional information may be of use here, but I wasn't the one who made the initial files and I've been given a few tasks to improve it, one being getting the search bar to use so it may be useful to know that there are multiple (quite a lot in fact) files in this project. A lot of these call different scripts as well, should I move all these scripts into my "jquery-ui-src.php" file? is it possible this would fix the error?

Comment: You have added `jQuery` twice

Comment: There are jQuery loads two time. one is new and another is older version

Comment: try to add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` after the main jQuery is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are importing another jQuery in the middle, hence everything you imported with your `jquery-ui-src.php` has been reset.

Please try removing this line:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

There is also invalid ending tag: `</div>//other code included here.` Remove it.

Below is the working code. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95m31edj/1/) .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<header id="header" class="website-header">
    <form role="search" action="" method="GET" style="width: 12em; margin: 0.1em 2em;margin-left:7em">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="tags" class="search-field form-control" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#account-dropdown").click(function() {
                $("#account-box").slideToggle(400);
                $(this).css("color", "white");
                return false;
            });
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"];

            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });

        });
    </script>
</header>
```

Comment: I've removed this line but I'm still getting the autocomplete is not a function error

Comment: I have updated my answer. The code given is tested to be working. If the answer helped, please accept as answer and upvote!

Comment: Still reciving the autocomplete error in both the file when changed to this and in the fiddle.

I've updated some info in my question, do you think it may be caused by the mutliple callings of the jquery script? If so I may have to take a while adding them all to the seperate jquery file

Comment: probably the cause of the error comes from somewhere outside of what you have posted in the question. you can try to find the cause by simplifying your code to bare minimum. First, remove all the html and javascript code. Second, test if you can import and use jQuery successfully by including just jQuery import line and try to run this line: $(document).ready(function(){alert('jQuery working');}); After that, test jQueryUI, then eventually to testing autocomplete with sample data taken from jqueryUI web page.